# Refreshing heat map in tkinter without closing window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some problems on refreshing frame in `tkinter`. I should close window to refresh my frame. My thermal sensor value is changing everytime. I looked `root.after()`, but i didnot get it.

**How can i do without closing it?**

*My code is here:*

```py
try:
    from tkinter import *
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from tkinter import *  # Python 3




f = open('text.txt', 'r')
nodes_list = [[int(item) for item in line.split()] for line in f]
heat_map = nodes_list
heat_min = min(min(row) for row in heat_map)
heat_max = max(max(row) for row in heat_map)
print('hello')
palette = (0, 0, 1), (0, .5, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, .5, 0), (1, 0, 0)


def pseudocolor(value, minval, maxval, palette):
    """ Maps given value to a linearly interpolated palette color. """
    max_index = len(palette)-1
    # Convert value in range minval...maxval to the range 0..max_index.
    v = (float(value-minval) / (maxval-minval)) * max_index
    i = int(v); f = v-i  # Split into integer and fractional portions.
    c0r, c0g, c0b = palette[i]
    c1r, c1g, c1b = palette[min(i+1, max_index)]
    dr, dg, db = c1r-c0r, c1g-c0g, c1b-c0b
    return c0r+(f*dr), c0g+(f*dg), c0b+(f*db)  # Linear interpolation.

def colorize(value, minval, maxval, palette):
        """ Convert value to heatmap color and convert it to tkinter color. """
        color = (int(c*255) for c in pseudocolor(value, minval, maxval, palette))
        return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*color)  # Convert to hex string.


root = Tk()
root.title('Heatmap')

width, height = 500, 500  # Canvas size.
rows, cols = len(heat_map), len(heat_map[0])
rect_width, rect_height = width // rows, height // cols
border = 1  # Pixel width of border around each.

canvas = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack()#goruntuyu gosteren kisim

for y, row in enumerate(heat_map):
    for x, temp in enumerate(row):
        x0, y0 = x * rect_width, y * rect_height
        x1, y1 = x0 + rect_width - border, y0 + rect_height - border
        color = colorize(temp, heat_min, heat_max, palette)
        canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color, width=0)


root.mainloop()
```

text.txt is like this.

```
22 5 9 15 22 20 20 20
22 33 32 15 22 22 20 20
23 34 33 15 22 22 20 20
25 35 35 15 22 25 20 20
12 15 35 15 10 5 20 20
15 40 33 15 3 5 20 15
16 32 25 15 12 22 50 15
13 32 31 15 5 22 23 13
```

Comment: The text.txt is updated by your heat sensor ?

Comment: Yes it is. It changes every 100 millisecond

Comment: I just give an example that what txt include. I can change it in my txt. However, frame doesnot change

Comment: Re run the `nodes_list` and whatever lines required to update the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `root.after` to repeatedly call a function that changes the colors of each rectangle.

I set up a random choice of the colors every second to demonstrate how this could work for you; you will probably need to replace this with the updated data collected at regular intervals from your heat sensor.

```
import random

try:
    from tkinter import *
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from tkinter import *  # Python 3


with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:   # <-- this construct automatically closes the file
    nodes_list = [[int(item) for item in line.split()] for line in f]

heat_map = nodes_list
heat_min = min(min(row) for row in heat_map)
heat_max = max(max(row) for row in heat_map)
print('hello')
palette = (0, 0, 1), (0, .5, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, .5, 0), (1, 0, 0)


def pseudocolor(value, minval, maxval, palette):
    """ Maps given value to a linearly interpolated palette color. """
    max_index = len(palette)-1
    v = (float(value-minval) / (maxval-minval)) * max_index
    i = int(v); f = v-i
    c0r, c0g, c0b = palette[i]
    c1r, c1g, c1b = palette[min(i+1, max_index)]
    dr, dg, db = c1r-c0r, c1g-c0g, c1b-c0b
    return c0r+(f*dr), c0g+(f*dg), c0b+(f*db)

def colorize(value, minval, maxval, palette):
        """ Convert value to heatmap color and convert it to tkinter color. """
        color = (int(c*255) for c in pseudocolor(value, minval, maxval, palette))
        return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*color)


def update_colors():
    for rect in rectangles:
        color = random.choice(colors)            # <--- replace with heat sensor data feed
        canvas.itemconfig(rect, fill=color)
    root.after(1000, update_colors)

root = Tk()
root.title('Heatmap')

width, height = 500, 500  # Canvas size.
rows, cols = len(heat_map), len(heat_map[0])
rect_width, rect_height = width // rows, height // cols
border = 1  # Pixel width of border around each.

canvas = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack()#goruntuyu gosteren kisim

rectangles = []    # <-- keep a handle on each of the canvas rectangles
colors = []        # <-- this to have a list of colors to pick from to demonstrate

for y, row in enumerate(heat_map):
    for x, temp in enumerate(row):
        x0, y0 = x * rect_width, y * rect_height
        x1, y1 = x0 + rect_width - border, y0 + rect_height - border
        color = colorize(temp, heat_min, heat_max, palette)
        colors.append(color)
        rectangles.append(canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color, width=0))

update_colors()

root.mainloop()
```

---

[Edit]:

If your sensor values come in a text file, you need to fetch them. This can be done by extracting the file opening in a function.

**pseudocode**

```
def get_sensor_values():
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
        return [[int(item) for item in line.split()] for line in f]  # <-- the nodes list
```

Then in the `update_colors()` method:

```
def update_colors():
    nodes_list = get_sensor_values()
    for node, rect in zip(nodes_list, rectangles):  # <--- make sure the nodes and the rectangles correspond to the same index in their respective lists
        fill = calculate the color value from the node value   # <-- the same way you already assign an initial color to each rectangle
        canvas.itemconfig(rect, fill=color)
    root.after(1000, update_colors)
```

Comment: 'rectangles = []    # <-- keep a handle on each of the canvas rectangles'
'colors = []        # <-- this to have a list of colors to pick from to demonstrate'

Should I update these two parts ?

Comment: No, you need to update the colors only, based on the value of your sensor.

Comment: with open('text.txt', 'r') as f: This part reads sensor value.as a string. |
nodes_list = [[int(item) for item in line.split()] for line in f]. This parts convert it to integer. | If i have sensor values in my nodes_list, How can i change this part ? color = random.choice(colors). Thanks for helping

Comment: Is there any way to take value as an integer not color value ? Because ıt will be between 15-50 degree. My nodes_list includes integer values. Also, fill = or color = which one ? If i give a value fill there is no change in my color. canvas.itemconfig(rect, fill=color) in this part

Comment: Yes, you can map temperatures with color strings in a dictionary: for instance  `colors = {10: '#00ce00', 11: '#0015d3', etc...}`, and access them like this: `fill=colors[temperature]`

Answer (score 0):

Here try this out.

Add this function to your code.

```
def repeat():
    global f 
    f = open('text.txt', 'r')
    # This function will be called every 100millisecs 
    root.after(100, repeat)
```

and call it just before `root.mainloop()` like this.

```
root.after(100, repeat)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: global f = open('text.txt', 'r')
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

End of statement expected. It showed that error

Comment: I've updated the answer please check. Sorry for the typo

Comment: No, it didnot work. I think. I only read text but i did not  write on nodes_list. It has sensor values